# Is it normal to get power supply surge when lightning cuts the electricity?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power, surge-protection

So I'm a bit worried because my previous MoBo (a Gigabyte) died and I just bought a new MoBo. This new MoBo is an Asus. Last monday (now we are friday) I've let my computer opened to be able to use it with TeamViewer. However, I didn't access the computer with TeamViewer and I didn't access it directly.

So when I came back friday, the screen was on a Power Supply Surge screen saying Asus is trying to protect my computer from PSU damage.

Also, a Storm occurred during the week and my house lost the electricity.

So I have the theory where its my PSU that killed my previous MoBo and I have the theory that the storm that occurred this week while my computer was here doing nothing caused the PSU purge. However, it is important to mention that my previous MoBo isn't really dead, it was just really unstable having random crashes and random behavior (like letting my fans runs for no reason when the temp was low). My GPU has always been fine and never seemed to be damaged by my PSU.

Now I'm writing this question just after the incident on this same computer, not sure If I should let it open.

So, was my PSU surge caused by lightning ? It is connected to a white bar and the white bar was powered on when I came back home. I have to mention that I'm a regular user and I do not own extra material to test with. Should I wait for another warning or one is enough ?

Specs:

- Intel Core i5 I5-4590
- Cooler Master Hyper 212
- Asus B85M-G Motherboard
- ZOTAC NVIDIA GTX 760
- Corsair CS450M CS Modular 80 Plus GOLD-RATE 450W 12V Power Supply
- Kingston HYPER 2x4GB RAM

Comment: You have a lot of theories with no substance... The most likely case here is the power "browned out" or dipped and your motherboard went into a special mode to protect it. The other likely possibility is the power surged a bit, and the Asus handled it but the Gigabyte MB did not. Was your PSU surge caused by thunder? No, thunder is just sound... Was your PSU surge caused by lightening or static electricity from the storm, quite likely. Most likely your equipment is fine, but a "white stick" is usually just a power stip and has no additional protection for your device, (continued)

Comment: You should get a good surge protector and verify your outlets are properly grounded.

Comment: @acejavelin How to know if my "power stip" is a surge protector ? It has many slots but one slot has a black border and that's the one I plug my computer on. It even have a blue led and there's the text "protected".

Comment: A power strip is a simple device to add additional outlets and may or may not have a simple circuit breaker. A surge protector comes in many sizes and layouts and often performs the same function as a power strip, but has additional circuitry in it to protect the equipment connected to it, some even having hundreds to thousands of dollars in warranty for it. Google can be your friend here but I would suggest starting with https://www.cnet.com/news/9-things-you-should-know-about-surge-protectors/ and http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-surge-protector/

Comment: I've searched for my surge protector and it's *1080 joules surge protection and $15,000 Connected Equipment Guarantee*. You said *Was your PSU surge caused by lightening or static electricity from the storm, quite likely* because *a "white stick" is usually just a power stip and has no additional protection for your device*. Does it still apply or now I should start thinking about the possibility of it being my PSU's fault ? In any case, thank you for the help you've given me so far through the comments. I'll also find a way to test is my outlets are properly grounded when I have the chance.

Comment: Your power supply is probably not "at fault" or the cause of the problem, although the power coming in could have caused it to malfunction and it could be damaged. In your Asus motherboard BIOS or it's software you should be able to look at the voltages and see if they are stable and within tolerance, if so the PS should be fine. If your surge protector is over 3 years old I would replace it. Remember that your surge protector generally can't work without a reliable electrical ground, but at the same time NOTHING can protect 100% against lightning damage.

Comment: @acejavelin My surge protector is older than 3 years old. I checked my voltages on the bios and they weren't changing at all. (even set on monitor) So I will change my surge protector and check the electrical ground. Thank you very much for your help. If youy feel like merging your comments into an answer, I will accept it. You gave explanation that, I think, would be useful for someone else worrying about his PSU and lightning.

Comment: I didn't really give you an answer... I could have flagged your question as off-topic or too opinion based, but I thought you needed some direction. If you find a verifiable solution, you can answer it yourself later. Good luck!

Comment: You could also consider a UPS which not only has surge built-in, but will run off battery if the line volts becomes to high or low to continue safely.  Most times the UPS will only have a few minutes of power, but that might be just enough.